# Levels of derailleurs, freewheels and chains

Tags: chain, gears, derailleur, freewheel, electric-bike

What are the levels of derailleurs (Shimano probably) I know Altus and Acera but don't know the higher end ones. I am putting this on my Sondors Fat ebike. I will be using a 7 speed freewheel, and a single sprocket in the front. 750 watt motor, 52 volt battery so I need strong chain, freewheel and derailleur. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Bike parts aren't really designed for that level of continuous power. You should probably look at mopeds instead.

Comment: You wont find high end components compatible with 7 speed.

Comment: Its not the gear count that matters here, its the actuation ratio, or pull ratio, and whether the limit screws let the rear mech move over enough.

Answer (score 2):

The higher end groupsets (Alivio and above) would not be the right Speed as you plan a 7 speed freewheel and they are all 9 / 10/ 11 speed.

Shimano's webpage has in the Trekking section:
Acera - 9 speed,
Alivio - 9 speed,
Deore - 10 speed,
Deore XT - 10 speed

In the Mountain bike range there is (lowest first):
Tourney TZ,
Tourney,
Tourney TX,
Altus,
Acera Altus,
Acera,
Alivio,
Deore,
Zee,
SLX,
Deore XT,
Saint,
XTR

I think the only derailleurs Shimano would say that work with 7 speed would be the Tourney rear derailleurs and the Acera RD-M360 8 speed derailleur, unless I've missed some.

But I can't see a reason that a 9 speed rear derailleur wouldn't work as the actuation is the same. The cage may possibly be fractionally narrower as its designed for the narrower 9 speed chain but I have heard of people running this with no issues. You would have to use a 7/8 speed chain though and not a 9 speed one.

Comment: Thank you Trevor, I have ordered a Tourney TX and all the rest including 7 speed freewheel, new chain, cable and shifter. I'll see how it works.